# Can't locate BeanDefinitionParser

Tags: java, spring

I am having a problem mapping a resource with mvc:resources.  I am getting the following error: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [resources]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]

I am using Spring 3.2.3 and eclipse.  The spring-webmvc.jar is on the build path.  I believe my schema is set up correctly.  If anyone could help, I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks!

```
<beans 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  

    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">
```

Comment: try using versionless schemaLocation and see if that works!

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Unfortunately, I'm still getting the error.  I change the schemaLocation to be this: 'xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">'

Comment: can you post how you are using the resources tag ? it should be prefixed with "mvc"  like `<mvc:resources ` since you are using mvc as namespace for this

Comment: Sure.  I use the following :         
      
 <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />

 <mvc:annotation-driven />
 
The part that's strange is that annotation-driven has no problems.  If I comment out resources...it works.  So, I'm confused as to why.  The css directory is under WebContent

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  Turns out it was a jar conflict.  There were multiple lingering org.springframework.*.3.0.1 jars in the build path.  Once I removed those, it worked.